# How to enforce "uniqueness" with boolean column (kinda like radio buttons)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean, unique

I have a table that describes a multi-to-one relationship, let's say between Pictures and Albums. I want to be able to select one and only one picture per album as the album's cover picture. Right now, the table is like this:

```
AlbumID int primary key,
PictureID int,
IsCover bool
```

Supposing that I don't want to change the overall schema (a solution could be to move the "is cover of" relationship to another table, defining a one-to-one relationship, but it is preferred not to change the already implemented queries by adding another table), is there a way to enforce that all of the entries with the same AlbumID BUT ONE have IsCover set to false?

I'm looking for server-side solutions. I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server 2012. The UNIQUE constraint can't be applied here, otherwise I could only have a cover and a non-cover for every album. I have already implemented a check in my application, but I would really like to have an additional layer of safety.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using a Trigger after update/after insert that checks whether the new entry is supposed to be the cover item and then marks all other relevant entries as false?

Comment: Using CHECK constraint you can enforce whatever rules you like on the table. Create a function that does the actual checking and use it in constraint.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! However, I'm trying to find out if there is something similar to the unique constraint, to keep things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably unique filtered index is the thing that may help you:

```
create table AlbumPics (
    AlbumID int not NULL,
    PictureID int not NULL,
    IsCover bit not NULL,
    primary key clustered (AlbumID, PictureID)
)

create unique index UX_AlbumPics_CoverPic
    on AlbumPics (AlbumID) where IsCover = 1

-- insert 3 pics for album 1, one of them is cover pic
insert into AlbumPics values
(1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 0)

-- try to insert one more cover for album 1 - will fail
insert into AlbumPics values
(1, 4, 1)
```

Comment: +1, but remember that "Filtered Indexes" are SQL Server 2008 and up.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx

Comment: Thanks i-one, this is exactly the solution I was looking for! Just one more thing: how can I ensure that there is always a cover for an album? The code above makes sure there's only one, but there could be none.

Comment: @Simone, apart from adding `CoverPictureID int not NULL` column to `Albums` table, I'm not sure there is any reliable way to enforce every album to have cover. If you can't change `Albums` table schema, I think, I would tried rather to ensure it on data retrieval, such as selecting special picture "No cover", when there is no cover for an album, or simply omitting such "dirty data" albums.